# How recommendable is it to access the value of a cell in a DataSet using the index of the column or the name of the column in C# ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am currently developing an application in *Webforms* with .NET 4.5.2, the architecture is very simple, only that it communicates to the *Data Access Layer (DAL)* and through SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter, etc. calls to stored procedures are made, from time to time I return a DataSet to the ASPX form.

How scalable is working the data sets by accessing the values of their cells using the index of their column?

I currently access them like this:

**Option A:**

```
string foo = dtResul.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

If I wanted to add a field to the stored procedure I would have to be very careful the order of the columns in the SELECT clause

But I have seen another way and it is like this:

**Option B:**

```
string foo = dtResul.Rows[0]["MyColumnName"].ToString();
```

Therefore I would not have the concern of the indices, but is it the same? Which one would you use and why? I've been thinking about changing it for the second way but I don't know if it should matter.

Comment: Curious why this question was down voted. It seems to meet the criteria for a valid question.

Comment: I think it becomes increasingly difficult to consult someone's opinion on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either approach is fine and one might fit your scenario better than the other, but there are advantages to indexing by the column name and I personally prefer it.

Here's why.

Let's say someone changed the stored procedure such that the order of two columns of the same type were swapped.

**If you're using a numeric index, everything may continue to work, but with no warning that the wrong column data are being used** by your code. At least until everything blows up for bizarre reasons that take a while to debug.

However, **if you were accessing by column name** in this scenario, assuming the columns were only re-ordered and not renamed, **then your code continues to work properly regardless of the re-ordering**.

Meanwhile, suppose the columns *were* renamed. Well, **now your code will fail during development and THAT IS GREAT**! Now you have been alerted that you need to fix something before it gets out to production.

Update: Regarding scalability, it's almost certainly not a concern either way. If you have less than a few thousand columns, I'm sure the performance hit of string lookups would be negligible compared to the cost of a database call. But if you're concerned, test it.